# How many digits are there in the product of $(3698765432123456789)$ and $(345678909876543)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving

How many digits are there in the product of $(3698765432123456789)$ and $(345678909876543)$? I could not find any formula to solve it and I  stuck in it.  Can you suggest any formula or way for it?

Comment: Ummm... trivial computer multiplication:  $1278585202465477044299954385200427$ ($34$ digits).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork sir, i have a computer;as well and i could have calculated it via my computer.But i want mathematical approach

Comment: If $3.6 \times 10^n < x < 3.7 \times 10^n$ and $3.4 \times 10^m < y < 3.5 \times 10^m$, then $1.224 \times 10^{n+m+1} < xy < 1.295 \times 10^{n+m+1}$.  So $x$ has $n+1$ digits, $y$ has $m+1$, and $xy$ has $n+m+2$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thank you very much for this elegant solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first number has $19$ digits, and the second has $15$. If you write them in scientific notation as $a\times 10^{18}$ and $b\times 10^{14}$, the product is $ab\times 10^{32}$. It’s clear that $10<ab<100$, so $ab\times 10^{32}$ has $2+32=34$ digits.

Comment: thanks for this elegant approach.

Comment: @harezmi: You’re welcome.

Comment: One nice way to get the inequality is to notice $3.25^2=(13/4)^2=169/16>10$, so $3.25<\sqrt {10}<4$

Comment: Isn't it more like $33+1=34$?

Comment: @WolfgangKais: No: $ab$ has $2$ digits to the left of the decimal point, and multiplying by $10^{32}$ gives you $32$ more digits.